# SharePoint 2013 list item in drop-down

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, orderby

Created a  page in which I have added a drop-down box . The drop-down box fetches all the ID's of a list .

I am fetching the ID by using REST API . In the endpoint url I have added `$top = 1000` to return only the top 1000 item IDs.

But the drop-down list only shows the item IDs till 2000. But I am having 2015 items in the list.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

I want the top 1000 ID's to be displayed in the drop-down box.

Answer (score 0):

this may be because the "top=1000" attribute will retrieve only the 1st 1000 items mostly based on other filters you might have applied. if the "ID=2000" is the 1000th item then it will show the item with the ID=2000 as the last item. there are two options you may want to try.

- Increase the retrieval limit  example, top=1015
- Try to use Sort "&$orderby=Id desc"

Hope one of the above method provides you the required result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest created items IDs, Sort list items in descending order while fetching the list items using REST api. Use `orderby` clause like given below:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Title,ID&$orderby=ID desc&$top=1000
```

**References**:

1. [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service).

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes that worked thankyou

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.